# WordPress TinyMCE custom button with input type number

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am creating custom button in WordPress TinyMCE.

All is going well but when creating number input field,I did not get any parameter to set its maximize & minimize value. Below is my code snippets of code. I tried to use "min" parameter but no success :(

```
   // Number of jobs
   {
     type: 'textbox',
     subtype: 'number',
     name: 'job_posts',
     label: 'Posts',
     min: -1,
    },
```

If anyone knowing the exact parameter, please help me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly your button is supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there're no ways to do it. But you can validate the input data.
For example:

```js
body: [
    {
        type: 'textbox',
        subtype: 'number',
        name: 'job_posts',
        label: 'Posts'
    }
],
onsubmit: function(e) {
    if (e.data.job_posts < min_value) { // Change min_value to your preference.
        // Do something.
    } else if (e.data.job_posts > max_value) { // Change max_value to your preference.
        // Do something else.
    } else {
        // Do other thing.
    }
}
```